# Publish After Commit not respected by InvokableApex?

Tags: platform-event

We do have a screen flow which invokes an Invokable Apex which produce a transactional insert of a graph of objects. To one of these SObjects we have attached a process builder which will publish a platform event whose publish behaviour to "Publish After Commit".

The Invokable Apex performs:

- an insert of one instance of SObject1
- an insert of a collection of SObject2
- an insert of a collection of SObject3

When the invokable apex fails after the first insertion, the process builder attached to SObject1 is executed anyways and the event is published, then write operation is rolled back and this creates an inconsistent system downstream.

Is this behaviour expected and how do we obtain a real "publish after commit" behaviour?

Comment: Is your code in a try-catch block? If you don't throw an exception, it is considered a successful transaction.

Comment: I do throw an exception and I receive an email from the screen flow that failed